# Java Singleton bean method with @PreDestroy annotation doesn't finish execution

Tags: java, rest, java-ee-7

I have RESTfull application that uses a singleton bean. The bean is managed by a Glassfish 5.1 container on Windows 10. When I shutdown the server, the bean's saveData() is called, which is suppose to save the application data into an XML file using JAXB. Looking at the log, the method is called by the container but it is not fully executed, hence an XML data file is not created.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
//This bean will be managed by the container automatically since it is a singleton. The container calls 
//the method that has a @PostConstruct annotation. This is ideal to perform initial data load into the
// the data store
public class DataLoaderSessionBean {

    @EJB
    private RequestSessionBean request;
    private final static String logPath = "C:\\Logs\\log.txt";
    private final static String dataPath = "c:\\Logs\\Parts.xml";
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerUtil.getLogger(DataLoaderSessionBean.class.getName(),
            logPath);

    @PostConstruct
    public void createData() {
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void saveData() {

        logger.entering(DataLoaderSessionBean.class.getName(), "saveData()");
        try {
            List<Part> parts = request.getAllParts();
            if (parts != null) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "The size of list to save {0}", new Object[]{parts.size()});
                parts.stream()
                        .forEach(e -> logger.log(Level.INFO, "saving part {0} {1}",
                        new Object[]{e.getName(), e.getNumber()})); 
                                
                PartWrapper warpper = new PartWrapper();
                warpper.setParts(parts);
                
                logger.log(Level.INFO,"Marshaller created");
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                        .newInstance(PartWrapper.class);
                Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
                m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                
                // Marshalling and saving XML to the file.
                m.marshal(warpper, new File(dataPath));
                
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Finished saveing data to {0}", dataPath);
            } else {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Warning: NO PARTS TO SAVE!!!!");
            }

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,
                    "JAXBException occured while saving data to XML: message {0} class {1}",
                    new Object[]{e.getMessage(),e.getCause()});
            StackTraceElement[] s = e.getStackTrace();
            for(StackTraceElement ste: s){
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Printing stacktrace element {0}",ste.toString());
            }
        }
        
        logger.exiting(DataLoaderSessionBean.class.getName(), "saveData()");

    }

}
```

Looking at the logs, it shows that method saveData() is executed up to the line where PartWrapper class in being instantiated, then the method execution somehow hats, and there are no exceptions thrown by the application nor the container. Here is a snippet from the log:

```
[2020-12-04T18:55:01.941+0330] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/C:/Users/mrr/Documents/NetBeansProjects/webdevelopment/RESTfulService/FromPattern/mavenlistservicedb/target/mavenlistservicememory-1/WEB-INF/classes/_listserviceDB.server] [tid: _ThreadID=221 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1607095500635] [timeMillis: 1607095501941] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Failed to find MBean Server: null or empty List returned from MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null)]]

[2020-12-04T18:55:02.052+0330] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [org.me.mavenlistservicedb.ejb.DataLoaderSessionBean] [tid: _ThreadID=221 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1607095500635] [timeMillis: 1607095502052] [levelValue: 800] [[
  The size of list to save 1]]

[2020-12-04T18:55:02.053+0330] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=221 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1607095502053] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Dec 04, 2020 6:55:02 PM org.me.mavenlistservicedb.ejb.DataLoaderSessionBean saveData
INFO: The size of list to save 1
]]

[2020-12-04T18:55:02.056+0330] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [org.me.mavenlistservicedb.ejb.DataLoaderSessionBean] [tid: _ThreadID=221 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1607095500635] [timeMillis: 1607095502056] [levelValue: 800] [[
  saving part Clutch Pressure Plate PP23864CL]]

[2020-12-04T18:55:02.057+0330] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=221 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1607095502057] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Dec 04, 2020 6:55:02 PM org.me.mavenlistservicedb.ejb.DataLoaderSessionBean lambda$saveData$1
INFO: saving part Clutch Pressure Plate PP23864CL
]]

[2020-12-04T18:55:02.157+0330] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/C:/Users/mrr/Document/NetBeansProjects/webdevelopment/RESTfulService/FromPattern/mavenlistservicedb/target/mavenlistservicememory-1/WEB-INF/classes/_listserviceDB.connection] [tid: _ThreadID=221 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1607095500635] [timeMillis: 1607095502157] [levelValue: 800] [[
  /file:/C:/Users/mrr/Documents/NetBeansProjects/webdevelopment/RESTfulService/FromPattern/mavenlistservicedb/target/mavenlistservicememory-1/WEB-INF/classes/_listserviceDB logout successful]]

[2020-12-04T18:55:02.219+0330] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=221 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1607095500635] [timeMillis: 1607095502219] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@4c3fefac]) and a value of type [org.glassfish.admingui.theme.AdminguiThemeContext] (value [org.glassfish.admingui.theme.AdminguiThemeContext@22bde63f]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.]]
```

Any idea?

Thanks